# esle condition not work in foreach loop php

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

My code:

```
$customers='[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "sara",
  "phone": 1100,
  "mobile": 1111
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "ben",
  "phone": 2200,
  "mobile": 2222
 }
]';
$data = json_decode($customers, true);
foreach($data as $a){
    if($a['name'] == 'sara'){
        $phone = $a['phone'];
        $mobile = $a['mobile'];
        echo "sara's phone is $phone";
        echo "sara's mobile is $mobile";
    }
    else{
    echo "No customer found with this name";
    }
}
```

my problem is:
just else part is working and if condition is not working but when i remove else part, if part is working good.
can you help me??

Comment: That can't be your actual code, you can not foreach over a _string_ value. Go and enable proper PHP error reporting, then it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: $customers is a string, you can't loop over a string

Comment: $customers is JSON that still needs to be decoded. See: https://3v4l.org/ciMLm

Comment: Your logic makes little sense to begin with - you can not output `No customer found with this name` while you are still looping over the data. It would output that text if the _first_ customer was not `sara`, even if the second one _was_ `sara`. You can only determine that `sara` was not found, after you iterated over _all_ customers.

Comment: Always ake sure you provide a [mre] of the issue, please (see also [ask]). If that _is_ your real code, then it's completely nonsensical to start with, as already mentioned. A JSON _string_ is not an array. It would need to be decoded for that to be the case.

Comment: sorry i forget write json decode in here, i edit question , this is example code and i write for shorting text

Comment: Initialize a boolean flag `$found = false;` before your loop, and inside, if you found a user, set it to true. Check on what it contains after the loop.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a variable to let the loop either return the wanted customer, or not. Like so: https://3v4l.org/Ce9T4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean variable with `false`

Iterate over the array and make this variable `true` in case the user found.

In the last check the final value of the variable and if it is `false` then show the message `No customer found.`

Here is a dynamic functional approach:

```
$data = json_decode($customers, true);

function findCustomerInArr($array,$customerName){
    $customerFound = false;
    foreach($array as $a){
        if(strtolower($a['name']) == strtolower($customerName)){
            $customerFound = true;
            echo $customerName."'s phone is ".$a['phone'].PHP_EOL;
            echo $customerName."'s mobile is ".$a['mobile'].PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(false == $customerFound){
        echo "No customer found with this name".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

findCustomerInArr($data,'sara');
findCustomerInArr($data,'aliveToDie');
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/fIJXu

Note: You can remove `strtolower()` in case you want case-sensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

You may Code the loop and condition like this, It may solve the problem.

```
$customers = '[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "sara",
  "phone": 1100,
  "mobile": 1111
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "ben",
  "phone": 2200,
  "mobile": 2222
 }
]';
$data = json_decode($customers, true);

$phone = Null;
$mobile = Null;
$name="sara";

foreach ($data as $a) {
   if ($a['name'] == $name) {
      $phone = $a['phone'];
      $mobile = $a['mobile'];
      break;
   }
}

if ($phone != Null && $mobile != Null) {
   echo "$name's phone is $phone \n";
   echo "$name's mobile is $mobile";
}else{
   echo "No customer found with this name";
}
```

Comment: This code is not as flexible as it can be. What if the programmer wants to add the age of the customer, or the address? Your code would balloon for no good reason.